# Setting unknown property: yii\grid\GridView::export

Tags: yii

I am a newbie to yii2 and learning it. I had installed yii2 export menu in my project, then it give error = Class 'kartik\dialog\Dialog' not found
then I installed yii2 dialod widget also now it is giving error

```
Setting unknown property: yii\grid\GridView::export
```

can anyone help to sort it out?

error is

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Setting unknown property: yii\grid\GridView::export
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-app\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php at line 201
192193194195196197198199200201202203204205206207208209210                $behavior->$name = $value;
                return;
            }
        }

        if (method_exists($this, 'get' . $name)) {
            throw new InvalidCallException('Setting read-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
        }

        throw new UnknownPropertyException('Setting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a property is set, i.e. defined and not null.
     * This method will check in the following order and act accordingly:
     *
     *  - a property defined by a setter: return whether the property is set
     *  - a property of a behavior: return whether the property is set
     *  - return `false` for non existing properties
2. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-app\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php at line 529 – yii\base\Component::__set('export', ['fontAwesome' => true])
```

Comment: You should show more code not just the error. As you see the only thing it says is that your `GridView` that you're running doesn't have the property `export`. Probably you have installed a different GridView widget but you're still calling the original Yii2 GridView instead of calling the new one that has this `export` parameter.

Comment: yes you are right .. i fixed it by installing yii2 dynagrid widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use yii2 export menu widget required widgets are=>
1 mpdf
2 dynagrid
3 dialog
then only we can use export menu widget